# Using page-worker to run background script doesn't work

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

My usecase is that I want to run a script which can listen to opening of any page. Then extract some info from that page and pass it on to a background page. I have used page-mod and page-worker respectively for this. But messages are not passed to a page script in my background.html

```
/*******************main.js******************/
var pageMod = require("page-mod");

var pageWorker = require("page-worker").Page({
  contentScriptFile: require("self").data.url("background_contentscript.js"),
  contentURL: require("self").data.url("background_local.html"),
});

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: ["*"],
  contentScriptFile: require("self").data.url("turn.js"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.on("turn-event", function(message) {
      console.log("Inside Main : PageMode message = " + message);
      pageWorker.port.emit("event-from-main", message);
    });
  }
});

/***************** turn.js*************/
self.port.emit("turn-event", JSON.stringify(document.title));

/**************background_contentscript.js*************/
self.port.on("event-from-main", function(message) {
  console.log("Inside background_local.js message = " + message);
  var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
  event.initCustomEvent("event-from-cs", true, true, JSON.stringify(message));
  document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(event);
});

/*********************background_local.html******************/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>background_local</title>
<script>
  document.documentElement.addEventListener("event-from-cs", function(event) {
    console.log("event detail message: " + event.detail);
  }, false);
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The message does reach background_contentscript.js, but never background_local.html. Am I doing something wrong here or it looks like a bug with SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Scripting Trusted Page Content](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-worker.html) section.